# What's the difference between this two regular expressions? (Understanding ? Quantifier)

Tags: javascript, regex, quantifiers

On book **Eloquent JavaScript** [chapter 9: Regular Expressions](http://eloquentjavascript.net/09_regexp.html) under Section "*Parsing an INI File*" there's an example which includes a regular expression I don't catch at all. The author is trying to parse next content:

```
searchengine=http://www.google.com/search?q=$1
spitefulness=9.7

; comments are preceded by a semicolon...
; each section concerns an individual enemy
[larry]
fullname=Larry Doe
type=kindergarten bully
website=http://www.geocities.com/CapeCanaveral/11451

[gargamel]
fullname=Gargamel
type=evil sorcerer
outputdir=/home/marijn/enemies/gargamel
```

On the rules for this format state that

> Blank lines and lines starting with semicolons are ignored.

The code which parses this content goes over every line in the file. In order to process comments, he include this expression

```
^\s*(;.*)?
```

As far as I understand, this expression process lines which may start with a sequence of

> white space characters, including space, tab, form feed, line feed and
>   other Unicode spaces

([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)) until it appears a semi-colon **;** and then a sequence of "*any single character except line terminators: \n, \r, \u2028 or \u2029.*". All this restricted to {0,1} appearances.

I don't get the point of quantifier **?** here. I'm not able to find ([regex101](https://regex101.com)) any case where not limiting appearances of matching string can be a problem. Why that expression is different to this other one:

```
^\s*(;.*)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `^\s*(;.*)` requires a `;`, it cannot match a blank line.

The `^\s*(;.*)?` can match an blank line, it does not require `;`.

The common part is `^\s*` - start of line (or string) and then zero or more whitespaces.

Then 1) `(;.*)` matches a `;` (1 instance obligatorily) and then zero or more characters other than newline, and 2) `(;.*)?` matches an optional *sequence* (the `(...)?` is an optional group since `?` is a quantifier matching *one or zero occurrences of the quantified atom*, while the *atom* can be a symbol, a character class, a *group*) of a `;` followed with  0+ characters other than a newline.

Also, note that `\s` matches an LF and CR symbols and that means that (if the MULTILINE modifier is ON and the input is a text containing multiple lines) the regex `^\s*` may match across several lines until the first non-whitespace character.

Comment: The text on the linked page says the input is first split into lines, so multiline mode is not used and there are no newlines for `\s*` to match.  (That caught my attention, too.)

Comment: Good, I modified the answer to *(if the MULTILINE modifier is ON and the input is a text containing multiple lines)*. It is a general note for future readers.

Comment: Thanks. I missed, the expression had to match also for blank lines. Thanks for answering so fast.

Answer (score 2):

Your modified final regex *requires* a semicolon. The original regex will match lines that are only whitespace.

Since the intent (if I'm understanding correctly) is to ignore the lines matched by this regex (as - ostensibly - comment lines) it makes sense to also ignore empty lines.

Comment: Thanks. Your commentary reinforce my understanding!